# Eloquent pagination result does not include data, next_page_url and other parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-pagination

The pagination is like this:

```
 Qitem::filter(Request::get("search") ?: "")
                ->withUserNames()
                ->withTrashed()
                ->paginate(10)
                ->onEachSide(1)
                ->withQueryString()
```

The returned data is different what is expected (even according to the docs):
[image: The returned result]

According to docs, there should be other attributes like prev_page_url, next_page_url, and instead of items, there should be a data attribute, containing the data from the table. It even behaves so if I simplify the query like:

```
Qitem::paginate(10)
```

Has anybody experienced similar phenomena? Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I faced a similar issue write on it here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/oneachside3-in-pagination-not-working-for-my-in-laravel-58

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes which response do you need, you can do it like:

#### JSON response

Create resource:

```bash
php artisan make:resource QItemResource
```

More about resources in [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#generating-resources)

Next in your controller:

```php
$items = Qitem::filter(Request::get("search") ?: "")
                ->withUserNames()
                ->withTrashed()
                ->paginate(10)
                ->onEachSide(1)
                ->withQueryString();

return QItemResourec::collection($items);
```

And you will get `next_page_url`, `prev_page_url` & `data`.

#### Collection

Just simply collect paginated data with `collect()`.

```
$items = Qitem::filter(Request::get("search") ?: "")
                ->withUserNames()
                ->withTrashed()
                ->paginate(10)
                ->onEachSide(1)
                ->withQueryString();

dd(collect($items));
```